# How to unarchive custom array with NSUserDefaults?

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoder

I'm saving an array of type ClassA to NSUserDefaults.  ClassA look like this:

```
class ClassA :NSObject, NSCoding{

    init (descriptionParam: String) {
        self.description = descriptionParam
    }

    var description: String?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if let description = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("description") as? String {
            self.description = description
        }
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let description = self.description {
            aCoder.encodeObject(description, forKey: "description")
        }
    }

}
```

This is how I'm saving the array to NSUserDefaults:

```
let myData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(ClassAManager.classa_array)
userDefaults.setObject(myData, forKey: "classAarray");
```

I'm doing the following in my initial viewDidLoad():

```
var classA: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaultsManager.userDefaults.objectForKey("classAarray") as AnyObject?
let classAunpacked = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(classA) as [ClassA]
```

I get the following compile-time error on the second line above (the one with `let`):

```
Cannot invoke 'unarchiveObjectWithData' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?)'
```

However, if I try to retrieve the array with anything other than AnyObject?, I get other compile time errors.  It also seems I can't cast from AnyObject? to [ClassA].  Any ideas how this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unarchiveObjectWithData` takes an `NSData` as it's sole argument, not an optional `AnyObject`.  Since the result of `unarchive...` is also an optional, I'd suggest using:

```
if let classA = NSUserDefaultsManager.userDefaults.dataForKey("classAarray") {
    if let classAunpacked = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(classA) as? [ClassA] {
        // Use classAunpacked here
    }
}
```

Comment: No more errors.  When I try to view classAunpacked via the debugger, it is just a memory address.  I can't see any array items.  Is there some way to view it? Also, I have checked /CoreSimulator/Devices/{someid}/data/library/preferences but all I see is com.apple.UIAutomation.plist.  Is the plist I'm modifying somewhere else?

Comment: You should use the nsuserdefaults method dataForKey   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/dataForKey:

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus: Excellent!  That works fine.  Also, while I can't see the entire array in the debugger, I can view each element by using "po classAunpacked[0].description" for example.  Thanks David for a great answer.

Comment: Any ideas where this plist file that is holding the data is located and what it is named?

Comment: You shouldn't try to manually edit those plists. You can use removeObjectForKey and reset/delete any value

Comment: you can use NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.array to check your keys

Comment: I'm not wanting to edit the file.  I want to view its contents.